# Formatting a .NET Entity Data model field before passing to the calling program?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am building an application using ADO.NET entity model and WEBAPI. I call the web API using jquery. I have a field in the model that returns a Julian date, and I have written a function to convert the Julian date to Gregorian date.

How can I pass the Julian date to the function in a LINQ query?

This is my code:

```
public IList Get()
{
    var query = from c in context.users_
                where c.id < 10000
                select
                    new
                    {
                        regdate= Julian(c.regdate) //error occurs on this line
                    };
    return query.ToList();
}
```

The data comes from an excel file which I have converted to a SQL Server database.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: What's the error? What's the database type of `regdate` and what do you want the `regdate` .NET property type to be? Where's your `Julian`  method?

Comment: @Cory probably something like _"can't translate `Julian(c.regdate)` to a store expression"_. OP: please use the search for the exact error.

Comment: regdate is an integer but i did a conversion, sory i dint add it to the code posted. `Julian(c.regdate.toString())`

Comment: @codecaster you are right. thats my error